# ¿Por qué sigo teniendo la posibilidad de buscar antes de compilar mi vim?

Tags: bash, vim

Soy nuevo en vim y necesito usarlo ya que no puedo usar Windows con Docker. Quiero configurarlo para que sea fácil y divertido de usar con este tutorial. Así que eliminé la carpeta ~/.vim y el archivo ~/.vimrc

Pero todavía puedo hacer la búsqueda con / (que acabo de descubrir)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, ¿eliminé los archivos/carpetas de vim equivocados?

Comment: ¿Por qué se relacionan los archivos de configuración con una funcionalidad?

Comment: Borrar la configuración de usuario no debería "quitar" la [búsqueda](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Searching) en vim.

Comment: O como analogía: borrar los archivos .bashrc no quita las funcionalidades de bash como apretar CTRL + R para buscar en el historial, o TAB para auto-completar.